# cache a array list of bitmap in android

Tags: android, caching, view, bitmap, android-sdcard

i have a ArrayList that contains more than 15 bitmaps. this bitmaps have to be read from sdcard. my array is in the loop .so i dont want to read bitmaps from storage each time and i want to save this bitmaps as cache. my arraylist of bitmap is less than 2 Mb.
i wanna display it with canvas in my Custom View.so i think it's good to save it as cache or something else because of the number of bitmaps. i think it doesn't make sense to read more than 15 bitmap from sdcard even if they are very light(about 15kb) pleas help me how to do this.
in additional each bitmap is 256*256 pixel.

```
Bitmap bmp;
String zoom = String.valueOf(ZoomLevel);
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/GreatMap/"+zoom);
File image = FolderExist(ZoomLevel);
if (file.exists())
{   
    if(image.exists())
    {
        for(int a = 1; a < 20 ;a++)
        {
            bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/GreatMap/"+zoom+"/"+a+".jpg");
            Images.add(a,bmp);                          

        }
        postInvalidate();

        }
}
```

Comment: and your question is ? (also, apparently you have 19 images, not 15).

Comment: Also, 256x256, in 8888 (32 bits), is 250Kb, which makes your array ~4Mb

Comment: it has been compressed with jpeg and make it 10-15Kb. [link]http://khm0.google.com/kh/v=132&hl=EN&x=0&y=0&z=0&s=  and also i wrote "more" than 15.

Comment: the bitmap returned by decodefile is a bitmap, not a jpeg. it therefore occupies 256x256xresolution (usually 4, sometimes 2, almost never 1), which makes it 250Kb (in memory, once decoded).

Comment: yes.that's right but for display it with canvas i have to use my jpeg as bitmap. in this case is it 250Kb while my image is 15Kb???

Comment: that's right. To display an image, you need to decompress the jpg in bitmap, and in your case this bitmap is 250kb

Answer (score 0):

Use below class to get image from sd card. It will remain image in  cache. You can get also image from url as well as from sd card. This will work for both.

Just initialize this class and get image.

```
imageLoader = new ImageLoader(this);
```

And call its method to get image from sd card and set photo where you want.

```
public class ImageLoader {

MemoryCache memoryCache = new MemoryCache();
FileCache fileCache;
private Map<ImageView, String> imageViews = Collections.synchronizedMap(new WeakHashMap<ImageView, String>());
ExecutorService executorService;
Handler handler = new Handler();// handler to display images in UI thread

Context mContext;
boolean imageWithReflection;

public ImageLoader(Context context) {
    fileCache = new FileCache(context);
    executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
    this.mContext = context;
    this.stubImageBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(), R.drawable.default_image);
}

final Bitmap stubImageBitmap;

public void displayImageFromUrl(String url, ImageView imageView, boolean imageWithReflection) {
    this.imageWithReflection = imageWithReflection;
    imageViews.put(imageView, url);
    Bitmap bitmap = memoryCache.get(url);
    if (bitmap != null) {
        if (this.imageWithReflection)
            imageView.setImageBitmap(createReflectedImage(bitmap));
        else
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    } else {
        queuePhoto(url, imageView);
        if (this.imageWithReflection)
            imageView.setImageBitmap(createReflectedImage(stubImageBitmap));
        else
            imageView.setImageBitmap(stubImageBitmap);
    }
}

private void queuePhoto(String url, ImageView imageView) {
    PhotoToLoad p = new PhotoToLoad(url, imageView);
    executorService.submit(new PhotosLoader(p));
}

private Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
    File f = fileCache.getFile(url);

    // from SD cache
    Bitmap b = decodeFile(f);
    if (b != null)
        return b;

    // from web
    try {
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        URL imageUrl = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) imageUrl.openConnection();
        conn.setConnectTimeout(30000);
        conn.setReadTimeout(30000);
        conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
        InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);
        ActivityUtils.copyStream(is, os);
        os.close();
        conn.disconnect();
        bitmap = decodeFile(f);
        return bitmap;
    } catch (Throwable ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        if (ex instanceof OutOfMemoryError)
            memoryCache.clear();
        return null;
    }
}

// decodes image and scales it to reduce memory consumption
private Bitmap decodeFile(File f) {
    try {
        // decode image size
        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        FileInputStream stream1 = new FileInputStream(f);
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream1, null, o);
        stream1.close();

        // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
        final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 70;
        int width_tmp = o.outWidth, height_tmp = o.outHeight;
        int scale = 1;
        while (true) {
            if (width_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE || height_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE)
                break;
            width_tmp /= 2;
            height_tmp /= 2;
            scale *= 2;
        }

        // decode with inSampleSize
        BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o2.inSampleSize = scale;
        FileInputStream stream2 = new FileInputStream(f);
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream2, null, o2);
        stream2.close();
        return bitmap;
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

// Task for the queue
private class PhotoToLoad {
    public String url;
    public ImageView imageView;

    public PhotoToLoad(String u, ImageView i) {
        url = u;
        imageView = i;
    }
}

class PhotosLoader implements Runnable {
    PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;

    PhotosLoader(PhotoToLoad photoToLoad) {
        this.photoToLoad = photoToLoad;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            if (imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                return;
            Bitmap bmp = getBitmap(photoToLoad.url);
            memoryCache.put(photoToLoad.url, bmp);
            if (imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                return;
            BitmapDisplayer bd = new BitmapDisplayer(bmp, photoToLoad);
            handler.post(bd);
        } catch (Throwable th) {
            th.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

boolean imageViewReused(PhotoToLoad photoToLoad) {
    String tag = imageViews.get(photoToLoad.imageView);
    if (tag == null || !tag.equals(photoToLoad.url))
        return true;
    return false;
}

// Used to display bitmap in the UI thread
class BitmapDisplayer implements Runnable {
    Bitmap bitmap;
    PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;

    public BitmapDisplayer(Bitmap b, PhotoToLoad p) {
        bitmap = b;
        photoToLoad = p;
    }

    public void run() {
        if (imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
            return;
        if (bitmap != null) {
            if (imageWithReflection)
                photoToLoad.imageView.setImageBitmap(createReflectedImage(bitmap));
            else
                photoToLoad.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        } else {
            if (imageWithReflection)
                photoToLoad.imageView.setImageBitmap(createReflectedImage(stubImageBitmap));
            else
                photoToLoad.imageView.setImageBitmap(stubImageBitmap);
        }
    }
}

public void clearCache() {
    memoryCache.clear();
    fileCache.clear();
}

private Bitmap createReflectedImage(Bitmap originalImage) {
    final int reflectionGap = 4;

    int width = originalImage.getWidth();
    int height = originalImage.getHeight();

    // This will not scale but will flip on the Y axis
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.preScale(1, -1);

    // Create a Bitmap with the flip matrix applied to it.
    // We only want the bottom half of the image
    Bitmap reflectionImage = Bitmap.createBitmap(originalImage, 0, height / 2, width, height / 2, matrix, false);

    // Create a new bitmap with same width but taller to fit reflection
    Bitmap bitmapWithReflection = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, (height + height / 2), Config.ARGB_8888);

    // Create a new Canvas with the bitmap that's big enough for
    // the image plus gap plus reflection
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmapWithReflection);
    // Draw in the original image
    canvas.drawBitmap(originalImage, 0, 0, null);
    // Draw in the gap
    Paint deafaultPaint = new Paint();
    canvas.drawRect(0, height, width, height + reflectionGap, deafaultPaint);
    // Draw in the reflection
    canvas.drawBitmap(reflectionImage, 0, height + reflectionGap, null);

    // Create a shader that is a linear gradient that covers the reflection
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    LinearGradient shader = new LinearGradient(0, originalImage.getHeight(), 0, bitmapWithReflection.getHeight() + reflectionGap, 0x70ffffff, 0x00ffffff, TileMode.CLAMP);
    // Set the paint to use this shader (linear gradient)
    paint.setShader(shader);
    // Set the Transfer mode to be porter duff and destination in
    paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.DST_IN));
    // Draw a rectangle using the paint with our linear gradient
    canvas.drawRect(0, height, width, bitmapWithReflection.getHeight() + reflectionGap, paint);

    return bitmapWithReflection;
}
```

remove or ignore extra code like createReflectedImage() method.

Answer (score 0):

Use https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader for better performance. This image loader will do what all you needed.